# Vector causing SegFault within Struct component Class Pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a struct that is suppose to serve as a manager:

```cpp
struct Manager{
    int item1, item2;
    Thing *item3;

    void Initialize();
};

void Manager::Initialize(){
    item1 = 0;
    item2 = 0;

    if (item3 == nullptr){
        item3 = new Thing();
    }

    item3->ClearList();
}
```

I want to be able to reference a class within it by pointer. This specific class has a vector within it:

```cpp
class Thing{
    private:
        vector<int> list;
    public:
        Thing(){list = vector<int>(0);}
        void ClearList() {list.clear();}
};
```

However after running it in this:

```cpp
int main(){
    Manager gm;

    gm.Initialize();

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i ++){
        cout << "Damn!" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Dude" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It just produces "Segmentation fault". I've located the bug to being the vector in Thing. The vector.size is a HUGE number, and trying to avoid using vector.clear by using `list = {}` produces the same result? What do I do? I could avoid using a pointer, I don't necessarily need it to be a pointer. But, the problem is still... well a problem.

Solution:
It seems I forgot that C++ does not initialize a pointer to null for whatever reason. So setting `item3 = nullptr` is the way to go.

Comment: `if (item3 == nullptr){` is UB, item3 is uninitialized. Stop writing C code and learn C++. `Initialize` should be a constructor for the class. `item3->ClearList();` only makes sense in a `Manager::ClearList` function, not to initialize the Manager.

Comment: What makes you think this `if (item3 == nullptr){` is true? Pointers do not automatically get initialised to null.